# Adding a button to a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, html-table

```
function OnSuccess(xml) {

  document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = "<tr><td>Employee ID</td><td>First Name</td><td >Last Name</td></tr>";

  $(xml).find('Table').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).find('EmployeeID').text();
    var fn = $(this).find('FirstName').text();
    var ln = $(this).find('LastName').text();

    //Create  button
    var btn = document.createElement("input");

    //Set the attributes
    btn.setAttribute("onclick", "ServiceCall3(id)");
    btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
    btn.setAttribute("value", "Info");
    btn.setAttribute("name", id);
    $('#people').append('<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + fn + '</td><td>' + ln + '</td><td> '+ btn + '</td></tr>')
  }

)};
```

Hey, this is my function which is creating a table from xml file.
What I need is to add a button with id same as read parameter from xml, a the end of each row.
What I am getting instead of a button is [object HTMLInputElement].
Please help.

Great, fast response.
Can you tell me now how can I pass id value to ServiceCall3 ? or use it in ServiceCall3 ?

```
function serviceCall3(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../TestWebService.asmx/GetAll",
                data: "{'data' :" + id + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: OnSuccess3,
                error: OnError
            });
             }
```

Comment: done, but my output is still the same

Comment: you tried what i mentioned in my answer? what you get if you console.log or alter(id) right before `//Create button` comment

Comment: Guys, can you tell me how can i pass id parameter to function ServiceCall3 ?

Comment: `btn.setAttribute("onclick", "ServiceCall3("+id+")");` ?

Comment: Aamir and how can I read it in servicecall then ?

Comment: Aamir adding "+id+" works, perfectly, how can i read it by ServiceCall now ?

Comment: `function ServiceCall3(id) { alert(id) }`

Comment: great, I have it all sorted now.
i was calling ServiceCall3 instead of serviceCall3
Thanks All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to concatenate a DOM element (`btn`) into a string (which causes the `[object HTMLInputElement]`). Instead you should append it:

```
$('#people').append(
    $('<tr></tr>').append(
        $('<td></td>').text(id),
        $('<td></td>').text(fn),
        $('<td></td>').text(ln),
        $('<td></td>').append(btn)
    )
);
```

This creates the row and four cells without concatenating content into raw HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is text already so just put `id` instead of `$(id).text()`

```
btn.setAttribute("name", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(this).find('EmployeeID').text();
```

You have specified `id` to be text.

But again, you are writing `$(id).text()`

```
 btn.setAttribute("name", $(id).text());
```

update the above line with

```
 btn.setAttribute("name", id);
```

Also you are trying to append btn to a string. Which is converting btn.toString to print the value.

Instead use append `btn` separately to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you write the button-element as a string:

```
<td> '+ btn + '</td>
```